# Can we use .set, .append or .replace command in ADX to combine data of Table A with Table B?

Tags: join, append, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have Table A which contains History data of 1 month(August 2022) and Table B in which I am doing real time ingestion . I want to ingest the data of Table A in Table B and also check if there is any duplicate data in Table B after combining data of both the tables.Can we use .append command to combine data of these tables without loosing my existing data?

How to use these tags in this code. I am bit confused on using these tags?

```
.append Table B with(tags='["TagA","TagB"]') <| 
   Table A
   | where timestamp between (datetime(2022-08-01 T09:00:00.000Z) .. datetime(2022-08-31 T11:00:00.000))
   | project  timeseries, value, timestamp, scaled_value
```

Answer (score 0):

###### 1.

Regarding set/append/replace, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query) is quite clear.
You need `.append`.

| Command | If table exists | If table doesn't exist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .set | The command fails | The table is created and data is ingested |
| .append | Data is appended to the table | The command fails |
| .set-or-append | Data is appended to the table | The table is created and data is ingested |
| .set-or-replace | Data replaces the data in the table | The table is created and data is ingested |

###### 2.

Regarding the tables` merge, it would be better to write a query that compares the two tables and returns only the data that is actually needed to be appended to table B (As opposed to ingest everything and then delete the excess data).

P.S.
If you need help with such a query, please open a new post for that.

###### 3.

You can read all about tags [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/extents-overview#extent-tagging).
Theoretically, as part of the ingestion process, you can mark your A table data with a `drop-by:` tag, so it could be identified after the merge into table B.

Comment: Have you read the answer?